# How to encrypt the SQLite database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, sqlcipher, flutter-dependencies

I am creating a database in Flutter by the following code, is there any way we can encrypt the database?

Is there any library available for Flutter?

```
initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "test.db");
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return theDb;
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

[Pointy Castle](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pointycastle) seems to be the encryption library of choice at the moment.

Comment: Do we have anything exactly like SQLCipher ??

Comment: @RajaJawahar Yes. See https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_sqlcipher

Comment: FYI - As of March16, 2020, Pointy Castle is no longer being maintained.

Comment: @eimmer PointyCastle has been moved here: https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart

Comment: What are the advantages of using SQLChieper rather than Pointy Castle?

Answer (score 1):

Current sqflite uses whatever sqlite version the platform provides. There is a discussion about that here that you could follow here:
https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/32

The only solution I am aware now is this one https://github.com/QwilApp/encrypted_sqlite which can be used as a drop-in replacement to sqflite which as you stated uses SQLCipher on the native side

Comment: Hi, @alextk You might want to update this answer with your library https://pub.dev/packages/sembast Thanks! :)

Comment: @DazChong well the question was about encrypting sqlite database, sembast is an alternative but it ain't no sql!

Comment: drift with encryption seems worth considering, then you do not have to "worry" bout where to store the key it looks like

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for such a library today.

And finally I found [flutter_sqlcipher](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sqlcipher) in pub.dev, which really solved my problem.

Here is the description of it.

> This is a Flutter plugin that bundles and wraps SQLCipher for Android, an open-source extension to SQLite that provides transparent 256-bit AES encryption of database files.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Caveat: 
_Android only, at present. (iOS support is planned.)_ [Source](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sqlcipher#compatibility)

Comment: Caveat: Not compatible with Dart 3